Copyright infringement when an image is turned into sound?
With the SoundArt app one can convert images into sound. It is possible to then convert the resulting sound files back into the same pictures.
Is such an audio file considered a derivative work, and thus constitute a copyright infringement?

You can very easily convert anything to sound by changing their extension to .wav . Windows will give you a warning, beside that it tries to hide the file extensions to keep you in the dark in the IT, but you can override these. It does not need any special.

Legally speaking, the sound "version" is not distinct from the original image.
Because there are so many ways in which an image can be represented digitally, copyright does not apply to a specific series of bits. Rather, it covers the work in all forms. For instance, in the US, Title 17, Chapter 1, Section 102 USC provides (emphasis mine):

Copyright protection subsists, in accordance with this title, in original works of authorship fixed in any tangible medium of expression, now known or later developed, from which they can be perceived, reproduced, or otherwise communicated, either directly or with the aid of a machine or device.

Transferring an image from one format to another is not a derivative work because a derivative work requires two works of authorship, as is clearly stated in section 103:

The copyright in a compilation or derivative work extends only to the material contributed by the author of such work, as distinguished from the preexisting material employed in the work.

Because there is no new original material involved, no new authorship, transferring a file from one digital format to another does not involve creating a derivative work. Even if the computer becomes convinced that the file is a sound instead of an image, legally, there is no such distinction. They're all different tangible media representing the same work.
Under section 106, the copyright holder has several exclusive rights: to produce physical copies of the work, to sell or rent those physical copies, to prepare derivative works, and to publicly display or perform the work. None of those rights are (necessarily) breached here: the work is not being displayed to the public, no new physical copy of it is being made or sold, and as mentioned above, no derivative work is prepared from it.
If you were to display/perform the resulting sound file publicly, or if SoundArt were to make all uploaded sounds available to the public willy-nilly, or if you were to curate several such files into a collection (which would be an act of authorship that creates a derivative work), any of those acts would separately be a breach of copyright. But the mere act of transforming file formats is not.
